# Does SSMS support a CRUD UI with the ability to select foreign keys?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

May i ask if SQL Server 2008-present has the same feature of `phpmyadmin` seen in this photo?

Wherein the photo below the `complaint_vehicle_type` data shown was from another table?

or does sql server has the same `insert gui feature`?

[image]

Comment: SQL Server does not come with a web interface, afaik. It comes with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which has a feature that lets you edit tables in a grid. It doesn't do automatic lookups to other tables for you.

Comment: SQL Server is a *database*, like MySQL. (MySQL *doesn't* have this feature; phpMyAdmin does. The "standard" SQL Server tool UI is SSMS, and SSMS does not support anything but the most primitive "row editor" for UI data entry.)

Comment: The closest you can get to this kind of feature in Sql Server will be a [`Database Diagram`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188251.aspx), It gives you a visual picture of Relations between tables.